# Where does SXA store css and js files on CM server

Tags: media-library

We can see `css` and `js` files in content tree under `/sitecore/media library/Themes/` and if we view source code of a web page we can also see the links. However I am not able to find those files in windows explorer. I am just wondering where those files are stored.

This is how it renders in the browser

`<link href="/virtualFolder/-/media/themes/projName/global/themeName/styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

but no such paths exist on CD server.

Answer (score 2):

They are stored in `media library`.

Just open content editor and expand

```
sitecore
 media library
  themes
   projName
    themeName
     styles
```

E.g.:

[image]

There are no files on the drive. There are just media item under those nodes holding content of those files.

Comment: "There are no files on the drive." this answers my question. Asking out of curiosity, where does CD server picks them from? Is there any article available explaining this procedure?

Comment: CD takes them in the same way like it takes images from Media Library. Content of the file is in database. When media item is published to web database it becomes available for CD server as well. Any url which contains "/-/media" tells Sitecore that it should not look on drive and that it should execute `MediaRequestHandler` instead and use content from the database under "media library" node.